# How do I assign json data to a paragraph when hovering over that element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want to assign different data for different elements.
When I hover over the first item I want to assign data from the first jsonObject `johnObj` and when I hover over the next div I want to assign the data from `sarahObj` to the paragraphs.

In the future I was going to add more divs and assign data so hardcoding the index might not be so good.

```js
var johnObj = {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"};

var sarahObj = {name: "Sarah", age: 40, city: "Oaklahoma City"};
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">
  <p class=radio> assign name here </p>
  <p class=radio> assign age here </p>
  <p class=radio> assign city here </p>
  </span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">
  <p class=radio> assign name here </p>
  <p class=radio> assign age here </p>
  <p class=radio> assign city here </p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `<p>` inside a `<span>` so I've changed a little your HTML.

```js
var johnObj = {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"};

var sarahObj = {name: "Sarah", age: 40, city: "Oaklahoma City"};


function asign(elmt,obj){
  let spans = elmt.querySelectorAll(".radio");
  spans[0].innerHTML = obj.name;
  spans[1].innerHTML = obj.age;
  spans[2].innerHTML = obj.city;  
}

let tooltips = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltiptext");

asign(tooltips[0],johnObj);
asign(tooltips[1],sarahObj);
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}

span.radio{display:block;}
```

```html
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <p class="tooltiptext">
  <span class="radio"> assign name here </span>
  <span class="radio"> assign age here </span>
  <span class="radio"> assign city here </span>
  </p>
</div>

<br>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
 <p class="tooltiptext">
  <span class="radio"> assign name here </span>
  <span class="radio"> assign age here </span>
  <span class="radio"> assign city here </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

But you can simplify it by removing all those spans in the HTML:

```js
var johnObj = {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"};

var sarahObj = {name: "Sarah", age: 40, city: "Oaklahoma City"};


function asign(elmt,obj){
  elmt.innerHTML = `
  <span class="radio">${obj.name}</span>
  <span class="radio">${obj.age}</span>
  <span class="radio">${obj.city}</span>
` 
}

let tooltips = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltiptext");

asign(tooltips[0],johnObj);
asign(tooltips[1],sarahObj);
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}

span.radio{display:block;}
```

```html
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <p class="tooltiptext"></p>
</div>

<br>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <p class="tooltiptext"></p>
</div>
```

### UPDATE:

the OP wants it "in a more dynamic way". In this case I'm putting the data in an array:

```js
var data=[
{name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"},
{name: "Sarah", age: 40, city: "Oaklahoma City"}
]


function asign(elmt,obj){
  elmt.innerHTML = `
  <span class="radio">${obj.name}</span>
  <span class="radio">${obj.age}</span>
  <span class="radio">${obj.city}</span>
` 
}

let tooltips = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".tooltiptext"));

tooltips.forEach((tt,i)=>{
  asign(tt,data[i])
})
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}

span.radio{display:block;}
```

```html
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <p class="tooltiptext"></p>
</div>

<br>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <p class="tooltiptext"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it without hardcode indexing? a more dynamic way of getting which element is hovered over?

Comment: Also why cant you put a <p> inside a span?